# pass index of element clicked in ng repeat from one page to other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass index of object by clicking from one page to other but it's not working.

The page from index that need to be sent looks like this

```
  <div><table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
    <td>{{profile.profileName}}</td><td>{{profile.created}}</td>
    <td>{{$index}}
    <button data-ng-click="showUser($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit </button>
    </table>
</div>
```

My `app.js` looks like this

```
var app=angular.module('message',['restangular','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "view/Home.html",
        controller : "MainCtrl"
    })
    .when("/NewUser", {
        templateUrl : "view/addUser.html",
        controller : "MainCtrl"
    })
    .when("/ViewUsers", {
        templateUrl : "view/ViewUsers.html",
        controller : "MainCtrl"
    })
    .when("/EditUser", {
        templateUrl : "view/EditUser.html",
        controller : "MainCtrl"
    });
}]);


app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,Restangular,$location){
    Restangular.setBaseUrl('webapi');
    var profiles = Restangular.all('profiles');
    $scope.selected;
    // This will query /profiles and return a promise.
    profiles.getList().then(function(profiles) {
      $scope.profiles = profiles;    
      $scope.saveUser=function(){
          $scope.profile.profileName=$scope.profile.firstName+$scope.profile.lastName;
          console.log($scope.profile);
          profiles.post($scope.profile);
     }

      $scope.showUser=function(id){
          console.log(id);
          $scope.selected=id;
          $scope.go('/EditUser');
      }
      $scope.editUser=function(id){
          console.log(id);
          var profile=$scope.profiles[id];
          console.log(profile);
          profile.put();
      }
    });




      $scope.go = function ( path ) {
          $location.path( path );
        };
});
```

and page to which value need to be passed look like this

```
name:<input data-ng-model="profiles[id].profileName" type="text">
date:<input type="text" data-ng-model="profiles[id].created" readonly="readonly">
{{$scope.id}}
<button data-ng-click="editUser(id)">Edit User</button>
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to separate the controllers because for all route you are using the same controller which is not a good practice. You should be using as below

```
.when("/ViewUsers/:id", {
    templateUrl : "view/ViewUsers.html",
    controller : "ViewUserCtrl"
});
```

Your controller should look like

```
app.controller('ViewUserCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams){
  var id = $routeParams.id;   
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZrX0K7HBcMtuoxMmYiib?p=preview)**

As I said, passing the data in the route parameter is not safe. How ever there are other alternatives but this will also lead to security issue.

Using **$rootScope**

Check my updated plunker here **[rootScope DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/by5dbyk5FCGoHphDGvI7?p=preview)**

Comment: I want profile info to be displayed on edituser page also. but according to your solution I hv to again make a restangular call.

Comment: what is that you exactly want?

Comment: I'm passing id and I have profile info so based on id I want to show complete profile information.

Comment: you should make a service request and get the data again. Because of security constraints. if you pass the entire object in the route parameter it is not safe.

Comment: @Naveen was it helpful?

Comment: yes it was helpful. Can you tell me where I can learn insights of angular like security constraint you mention .

Comment: Security as in? What exactly you are looking for list of few sample security

Comment: From where I can understand things like this"pass the entire object in the route parameter it is not safe" and advance learning of angular

Comment: Aravind and @suzo thanks for helping me out. I already upvoted. Once my reputation will be more than 15, my upvote will became public.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `route` to accept param using `$routeprovider` query params in the url as shown below

```
.when("/ViewUsers:index", {
    templateUrl : "view/ViewUsers.html",
    controller : "MainCtrl"
});
```

And now when you to change the view, there is no method called `$scope.go()` you have to use [**$location.path()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to go the view and use `.search()` method to add the query param.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $location){
  $scope.showUser=function(id){
      console.log(id);
      $scope.selected=id;
      $location.path('/EditUser/').search({index: id});  // this will create the url as **/EditUser/?index=id**
  }
});
```

And in other controller where you want to access the index, it is available in the [**$routeparams**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) object as shown below

```
app.controller('EditCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams){
  var index = $routeParams.index;   //This has the value passed from the other controller
});
```

Comment: Did you add `:index` in the config ?